# pass value from list with data-value to a mysql query

Tags: php, jquery

I have a list

```
<ul id="my_ul">
<li data-value="1"><a href="test.php">111</a></li>
<li data-value="2"><a href="test.php">112</a></li>
<li data-value="3"><a href="test.php">113</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried to pass the `data-value` on click event to MySQL query. I tried it with jQuery but when i `var_dump` the result its NULL.

Here is how i am getting the value

```
$('#my_ul').on("click", "li", function(){
   $.ajax("fetch_test.php",{method:"post", data:{val:$(this).attr("data-value")}}); 
});
```

and here is the `fetch_test.php` file code :

```
function showValue(){
include_once "connect.php";
$test=$_SESSION['val'];
$query="SELECT * FROM product INNER JOIN smetka on smetka.id=product.smetka_id WHERE product.smetka_id=$test";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $alert="";
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $alert .="<li data-value='$row[id]'><a href='test.php'>$row[name]";

            $alert .= "</a></li>";
        }
    return $alert;
}
```

How can i pass the `data-value` from the `li`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the event handler with anchor element and use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to cancel its the default action. You can use `.closest()` to traverse up to `li` element.

```js
$('#my_ul').on("click", "li a", function(e) {
  //Cancels default action of anchor
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $(e.target).closest('li').data("value");
  console.log(value);
  $.ajax({url: "fetch_test.php", method:"post", data:{val:value}});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="my_ul">
  <li data-value="1"><a href="test.php">111</a></li>
  <li data-value="2"><a href="test.php">112</a></li>
  <li data-value="3"><a href="test.php">113</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it works with console.log, but when i try to pass it with the second command it's still NULL. How do i have to 'get' the value with _SESSION vs _POST?

Comment: @PeyoPeev see updated answer, you were not passing g the correct argument to ajax method

Comment: Again it just log the value and don't pass it.

Comment: @PeyoPeev, I am not a php guy, however aren't you supposed to read from `$_POST` instead of `$_SESSION`

Comment: i try with both, the result is the same "Undefined index: value" it doesn't pass the result

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent redirection to test.php

Instead of

```
$('#my_ul').on("click", "li", function(){
   $.ajax("fetch_test.php",{method:"post", data:{val:$(this).attr("data-value")}}); 
});
```

Use

```
$('#my_ul').on("click", "li", function(event){
event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax("fetch_test.php",{method:"post", data:{val:$(this).attr("data-value")}}); 
});
```